# Django code pretifier for HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, prettify

I'm new in Django, and I'd like to know if there is any **JQuery** library to prettify Django code.

I have a web site in **PHP** and I'd like to show some **Django** code prettified, there is only 2 possible syntax in Django template `{{ }}` or `{% %}` I was thinking in use [Javascript code prettifier](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) but it doesn't have support for Django.

- Does anybody know any library to prettify Django code ?

I don't know if there is any library with Django integrated, if it doesn't exist I could add myself the syntax to highlight Django code

Comment: Have you checked out Beautifulsoup?

Comment: @dan-klasson I've worked with BeautifulSoup but never as code prettify, I'm going to google about it, thanks for the info !